# Match values in column 2 on four other sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have 6 worksheets. The first has a list of ids (eg, 1.1.3, 1.2.3, 1.3.3 etc.) in column 6 (Rows 13 to 29) that I want to match to values in column 2 on four of the other sheets.

If I find a match I want to write the name of the sheet containing the match in the first empty cell of the row that contains the id.  Note There may be multiple matches of an individual id within one or more the sheets being searched.

The routine runs without error but there is no output.

```vb
Private Sub Command_MapComp_Click()

    Dim BP As Worksheet
    Set BP = Sheets("Blue Print")
    Dim CF As Worksheet
    Set CF = Sheets("Competency Framework")
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim lc As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim FindVal As String

'Loop through each cell in Column 6 from Row 13 to 29 and store its value in the "findVal" variable

    For i = 13 To 29
        FindVal = BP.Cells(i, 6).Value
'Locate Last empty cell in Row "i":
        lc = BP.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    
'Loop each sheet in the workbook
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
            If ws.Name = BP.Name Or ws.Name = CF.Name Then
                'Do nothing

            Else
'Loop each cell in Column 2 in ws from Row 8 to Last Row to find the "FindVal" variable
    
                lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlTUp).Row
        
                For j = 8 To lr
                    If Cells(j, 2).Value = FindVal Then
    
'Enter the name of the Worksheet in the first empty cell in Row "i"
                        BP.Cells(i, lc).Value = ws.Name
    
                Next j
    
            End If
        
        Next
   Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: "The routine runs without error " REALY!!!!!!  End(xlTUp)    ........ If Cells(j, 2).Value = FindVal Then  .... without End if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Find Strings in Other Worksheets

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command_MapComp_Click()

    Dim BP As Worksheet: Set BP = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blue Print")
    Dim CF As Worksheet: Set CF = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Competency Framework")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim lc As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim FindVal As String

    'Loop through each cell in Column 'F' from row 13 to 29
    'and store its value in the 'findVal' variable
    For i = 13 To 29
        FindVal = CStr(BP.Cells(i, "F").Value)
        'Locate the last empty cell in row 'i':
        lc = BP.Cells(i, BP.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        'Loop each sheet in the workbook
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name = BP.Name Or ws.Name = CF.Name Then
                'Do nothing
            Else
                'Loop each cell in Column 'B' in the worksheet from Row 8
                'to the last row to find the value of the 'FindVal' variable
                lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                For j = 8 To lr
                    If ws.Cells(j, "B").Value = FindVal Then
                        'Write the name of the worksheet to the first empty
                        'cell in row 'i'
                        BP.Cells(i, lc).Value = ws.Name
                        lc = lc + 1
                        Exit For ' it's been found, no need to loop anymore
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        Next ws
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

When cycling through the worksheets to find the value, you're not specifying which sheet to scan - so it will only ever scan the active sheet.

```
If Cells(j, 2).Value = FindVal Then
```

should be

```
If ws.Cells(j, 2).Value = FindVal Then
```

Also, as pointed out in the comments, there is a slight problem with a typo which should be causing an error, not to mention the IF block structure issue. Lastly, you weren't recalcing lc inside the loop so if a value is on more than one sheet, it will overwrite rather than append. I've resolved these in the code here and tested it - it works without errors - it does what you have described and outputs the sheetnames.

```
 Private Sub Command_MapComp_Click()

    Dim BP As Worksheet
    Dim CF As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim lc As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim FindVal As String

    Set BP = Sheets("Blue Print")
    Set CF = Sheets("Competency Framework")

    'Loop through each cell in Column 6 from Row 13 to 29 and store its value in the "findVal" variable
    For i = 13 To 29
    
        FindVal = BP.Cells(i, 6).Value
        
        'Loop each sheet in the workbook
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        
            'Locate Last empty cell in Row "i":
            lc = BP.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        
            If ws.Name = BP.Name Or ws.Name = CF.Name Then
          
            'Do nothing
            
            Else
        
                'Loop each cell in Column 2 in ws from Row 8 to Last Row to find the "FindVal" variable
                lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
                    For j = 8 To lr
                        If ws.Cells(j, 2).Value = FindVal Then
        
                            'Enter the name of the Worksheet in the first empty cell in Row "i"
                            BP.Cells(i, lc).Value = ws.Name
                        
                    End If
               Next j
            End If
        Next
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I made that correction but still no output

Comment: See addition to answer. You should be fine now.